# How to implement inline editing on datatables in R Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I am running an R Shiny web-app. I used datatables to show the data. But I want the inline editing of cell of the tables. I am unable to do that. Can any one guide me?

Here is my code in

```
# UI.R

fluidRow(
         column(4,dataTableOutput("numericalBin")),
         column(8,h1("numericalBin_Chart")))
)
```

---

```
# Server.R

output$numericalBin <- renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  },options = list(    
    lengthChange=FALSE,
    searching=FALSE,
    autoWidth=TRUE,
    paging=FALSE
  ))
```

I want to edit cell. Here is the link I want to do the effect:
**https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html**

I need something to add in option list maybe but I can not find the right one.

Comment: This one is interesting indeed, I would like to hear from others how they would go about it. But for now I would go and use the shinyBS library and its modals via bsModal to link the dependencies that would pop up and do what you want...

Comment: There is a prototype of editor for DT [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28)

Answer (score 13):

Apart from DT prototype proposed by @dracodoc, another option is using [rhandsontable package](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#shiny).

EDIT: according to comments by @hveig and @Munawir, a piece of working example code is now attached (adapted from [rhandome examples page](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/tree/master/inst/examples)):

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    fluidRow(
      rHandsontableOutput("hot")
    )),

  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    values = reactiveValues()

    data = reactive({
      if (!is.null(input$hot)) {
        DF = hot_to_r(input$hot)
      } else {
        if (is.null(values[["DF"]]))
          DF = mtcars
        else
          DF = values[["DF"]]
      }


      values[["DF"]] = DF
      DF
    })

    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
      DF = data()
      if (!is.null(DF))
        rhandsontable(DF, stretchH = "all")
    })
  })
)
```