# Can you use R's native data editor to edit a csv from within Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Much like the edit function in R, I would like to manually make changes to a data frame from within Shiny. I have been to the shiny website

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html

however, I have not find a place where I can manually change data.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636931/how-to-implement-inline-editing-on-datatables-in-r-shiny) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263627/shiny-r-application-that-allows-users-to-modify-data)?

Comment: Yes, trestletech package has not been updated in awhile and I couldn't get it to install. While the second one provides a theoretical answer, which doesn't have a concrete solution, which is why I posted the question. But we're definitely on the same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do what you want with [`shinysky`](https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky) package. It offer functionality to edit your tables on demand. Below is a simple example with `mtcars` dataset where you can change the table content and then download the updates you introduced during the session. You can easily add the file input to read `.csv` files yourself

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinysky)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "How to edit a table"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",menuItem("Menu Item 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dashboard"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "one",hotable("hotable1"),downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')))
    ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  previous <- reactive({mtcars})
  sample_data <- reactive({

    if(is.null(input$hotable1)){return(previous())}
    else if(!identical(previous(),input$hotable1))
    {
      sample_data <- as.data.frame(hot.to.df(input$hotable1))
      sample_data
    }
  })
  output$hotable1 <- renderHotable({sample_data()}, readOnly = F)
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(filename = function() {paste(Sys.time(), '- My New Table.csv', sep='') },content = function(file) {write.csv(sample_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**The downloaded file looks like so:**

[image]

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the downloaded file, it never game me an option to choose the file type. Everything else was very smooth after downloading shinysky

Comment: As per my example, everything should work. If you're using additional code, that might be breaking it. For the download, please refer to `downloadHandler` where I specified it would automatically download `.csv` format

Comment: Problem solved: I had to change run App to run External in RStudio